# Move all the files from a ZIP archive to another

Tags: c++, zip, unzip

I am searching for a few days a library that just has to move all the files in a ZIP archive, to another in C++. I found libzip, but it it is better just for some files that you know the names. I don't care of the steps between the archive A and the archive B, as long as it doesn't take too much time. (and if possible, it will remove the files in its temporary folder). And I prefer a portable library.

Thanks you!

Comment: Why not make your life a lot more simpler and write a little script? You can then use the `system` function within your C++ program to execute this script.

Comment: What system are you on? The answers will vary greatly depending upon unix/windows.

Comment: Because I would like my program to be portable. If it was only for Linux, it would be easy. But it is also for Windows, and there are no zip/unzip equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libzip is probably the best bet.

You can use [`zip_get_num_entries`](http://www.nih.at/libzip/zip_get_num_entries.html) to get the number of files in an archive, then use [`zip_get_name`](http://www.nih.at/libzip/zip_get_name.html) to get the file-name of a specific file. Use [`zip_fopen_index`](http://www.nih.at/libzip/zip_fopen.html) to open a file inside the archive, [`zip_fread`](http://www.nih.at/libzip/zip_fread.html) to read the file (and save either to disk or to another zip archive) and when done [`zip_fclose`](http://www.nih.at/libzip/zip_fclose.html) to close the file. If you want to remove the file from the archive use [`zip_delete`](http://www.nih.at/libzip/zip_delete.html).

Continue to do this in a loop for all files, starting with the highest index down to index zero.

---

As for libzip on Windows, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12239625/440558) (or if it doesn't work [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508376/440558)).

Comment: Oh I missed those functions by searching on the wrong way! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the precision, but I had already built zlib and libzip on Windows with CMake ;-)