# static libzip with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, zip

I am trying to build a little application using libzip library.
I downloaded and compiled libzip with assistance of this article:

[libzip with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507893/libzip-with-visual-studio-2010)

The problem is that it compiles libs dynamically, requiring both zlib.dll and zip.dll to be present.
I want to compile the application completely statically, so no additional dlls will be required. does someone know how I can do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Ok... here is the deal:

You need to go to file ***lib\CMakeLists.txt*** and add at the end (Line in black)

ADD_LIBRARY(zip SHARED ${LIBZIP_SOURCES} ${LIBZIP_EXTRA_FILES})

**ADD_LIBRARY(zipstatic STATIC  ${LIBZIP_SOURCES} ${LIBZIP_EXTRA_FILES})**

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(zip PROPERTIES VERSION 3.0 SOVERSION 3 )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(zip ${ZLIB_LIBRARY})

INSTALL(TARGETS zip
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)

Comment: This results in this error for me: -- Configuring done
CMake Error at lib/CMakeLists.txt:173 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  No SOURCES given to target: zipstatic

Answer (score 1):

> Ok... here is the deal:
>
> You need to go to file lib\CMakeLists.txt and add at the end (Line in black)
>   You need to go to file lib\CMakeLists.txt and add at the end (Line in black)
>
> ...

Correct string for libzip v1.5.1 is:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(zipstatic STATIC ${LIBZIP_SOURCES} ${LIBZIP_EXTRA_FILES} ${LIBZIP_OPTIONAL_FILES} ${LIBZIP_OPSYS_FILES})
```