# libzip Windows compilation for libraries

Tags: windows, static-libraries, libraries, dynamic-library, libzip

I need libzip.lib .h to use libzip in other projects. So I followed [libzip with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507893/libzip-with-visual-studio-2010) and all is fine until step 11. In fact, I open C:\devel\libzip-0.10.1\build\libzip.sln, execute "Generate the solution" and I get the following errors :

First :

2>  zip_set_file_compression.c

2>....\lib\zip_set_file_compression.c(63): error C2275: 'zip_int32_t' : non conform use of this type as expression

2>          C:/devel/libzip-0.11.1/lib\zipconf.h(33) : see declaration of 'zip_int32_t'

2>....\lib\zip_set_file_compression.c(63): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'old_method'

2>....\lib\zip_set_file_compression.c(63): error C2065: 'old_method' : non declared identifier

2>....\lib\zip_set_file_compression.c(67): error C2065: 'old_method' : non declared identifier

I didn't change anything in source files so ... I don't understand. I'll check the file to see but I don't want to change things and then nothing works!

And secondly :

LINK : fatal error LNK1181: impossible to open file '..\lib\Release\zip.lib'

And indeed, I don't have any zip.lib file! Where do I get it? Has it to be created/generated in one of the steps 1 to 10? Do I have to get it on web?

Answer (score 0):

The variable is declared inside the block, C++ style. You have to declare it at the top of the block, C style. This bug is corrected in the daily tarball.

However many other errors stay and I, too, am unable to compile and link libzip with Visual.