# zip_open gives an unknown error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, libzip

I'm using libzip but I can't even use it. I'd like to create a new zip file.

```
zip_open("/path/to/my.zip", ZIP_CREATE, &err)
```

gives me this error code : `-858993460`

I compiled zlib and then libzip myself successfully (since I get no error) for both debug and release in Visual Studio. I followed instructions from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507893/libzip-with-visual-studio-2010).

What do I miss?

Comment: You miss reading of documentation that tells you what that error code means.

Comment: How do you obtain the the error? In particular, how is `err` initialized and how is it printed?

Comment: -858993460 is 0xCCCCCCCC which is what VS will initialize memory to in debug mode. This may mean that `err` wasn't changed at all by the `zip_open` call. Try setting `err` to 0 before the call to verify it's being changed. Is `zip_open` returning NULL to indicate an error occurred?

Comment: If I put 0 to `err`, it won't be changed. So does it actually mean it's ok? However, `zip_source_file` and `zip_file_add` still don't add the file into the archive.

Comment: Ok, I know why it didn't create the zip. It is because the length parameter for `zip_source_file`. It must be -1 in order to process the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue thanks to comments in my question. Actually, my work is working. It is just that `err` variable must be initialized to 0 since when there is no error, `err` is not automatically updated. If not initialized, VS will do by itself with `0xCCCCCCCC` which is actually `-858993460` in decimal.

So the code should looks like this:

```
int err = 0;
zip_t *myzip = zip_open("/path/to/my.zip", ZIP_CREATE, &err);
```