# Error in installing libpng for windows x64

Tags: python, visual-studio, libpng

I'd tried install and reinstall `libpng` from http://libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html. I need this to use for face verification using [bob](http://pythonhosted.org/bob.example.faceverify/examples.html) (hosted by **python**). I'd followed the first step by installing `libzip` and `ziplib` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507893/libzip-with-visual-studio-2010). However I keep getting error.

Here I list the result from `cmake`:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Found ZLIB: c:/Python27/work/libpng-1.6.26/lib/zlib.lib (found version "1.2.8")
-- Performing Test HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT
-- Performing Test HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_SOLARIS_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT
-- Performing Test HAVE_SOLARIS_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT - Failed
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Python27/work/libpng-1.6.26/libpng-1.6.26
```

Then, this is I get when build `libpng.sln`:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning MSB8028 The intermediate directory (x64\Debug\) contains files shared from another project (png.vcxproj, pngfix.vcxproj, pngimage.vcxproj, pngstest.vcxproj, pngtest.vcxproj, pngunknown.vcxproj, pngvalid.vcxproj, png_static.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.    png-fix-itxt    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets   392 
Warning MSB8028 The intermediate directory (x64\Debug\) contains files shared from another project (png-fix-itxt.vcxproj, pngfix.vcxproj, pngimage.vcxproj, pngstest.vcxproj, pngtest.vcxproj, pngunknown.vcxproj, pngvalid.vcxproj, png_static.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.   png C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets   392 
Error   LNK1112 module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'  png C:\Python27\work\libpng-1.6.26\libpng-1.6.26\x64\Debug\png.obj  1   
Error   LNK1112 module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'  png-fix-itxt    C:\Python27\work\libpng-1.6.26\libpng-1.6.26\x64\Debug\png-fix-itxt.obj 1   
Warning MSB8028 The intermediate directory (x64\Debug\) contains files shared from another project (png-fix-itxt.vcxproj, png.vcxproj, pngfix.vcxproj, pngstest.vcxproj, pngtest.vcxproj, pngunknown.vcxproj, pngvalid.vcxproj, png_static.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.    pngimage    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets   392 
Warning MSB8028 The intermediate directory (x64\Debug\) contains files shared from another project (png-fix-itxt.vcxproj, png.vcxproj, pngimage.vcxproj, pngstest.vcxproj, pngtest.vcxproj, pngunknown.vcxproj, pngvalid.vcxproj, png_static.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.  pngfix  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets   392 
Warning MSB8028 The intermediate directory (x64\Debug\) contains files shared from another project (png-fix-itxt.vcxproj, png.vcxproj, pngfix.vcxproj, pngimage.vcxproj, pngstest.vcxproj, pngtest.vcxproj, pngvalid.vcxproj, png_static.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.  pngunknown  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets   392 
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'Debug\libpng16d.lib'  pngimage    C:\Python27\work\libpng-1.6.26\libpng-1.6.26\LINK   1   
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'Debug\libpng16d.lib'  pngunknown  C:\Python27\work\libpng-1.6.26\libpng-1.6.26\LINK   1   
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'Debug\libpng16d.lib'  pngfix  C:\Python27\work\libpng-1.6.26\libpng-1.6.26\LINK   1   
Warning MSB8028 The intermediate directory (x64\Debug\) contains files shared from another project (png-fix-itxt.vcxproj, png.vcxproj, pngfix.vcxproj, pngimage.vcxproj, pngtest.vcxproj, pngunknown.vcxproj, pngvalid.vcxproj, png_static.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.    pngstest    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets   392 
Warning MSB8028 The intermediate directory (x64\Debug\) contains files shared from another project (png-fix-itxt.vcxproj, png.vcxproj, pngfix.vcxproj, pngimage.vcxproj, pngstest.vcxproj, pngtest.vcxproj, pngunknown.vcxproj, png_static.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.    pngvalid    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets   392 
Warning MSB8028 The intermediate directory (x64\Debug\) contains files shared from another project (png-fix-itxt.vcxproj, png.vcxproj, pngfix.vcxproj, pngimage.vcxproj, pngstest.vcxproj, pngunknown.vcxproj, pngvalid.vcxproj, png_static.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.   pngtest C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets   392 
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'Debug\libpng16d.lib'  pngvalid    C:\Python27\work\libpng-1.6.26\libpng-1.6.26\LINK   1   
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'Debug\libpng16d.lib'  pngtest C:\Python27\work\libpng-1.6.26\libpng-1.6.26\LINK   1   
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'Debug\libpng16d.lib'  pngstest    C:\Python27\work\libpng-1.6.26\libpng-1.6.26\LINK   1
```

As far as I know, the one that I should deal is version x64. And also it looks like `cmake` does not perform correctly. But I don't get any idea on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you selected the correct generator with CMake ? As far as I know you need to pick "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" as target name if you want to build 64 bit binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I installed libpng successfully following the steps from that answer just now.I don't think you installed it correctly because I once saw these results when I installed incorrectly.

> -- Performing Test HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT
>
> -- Performing Test HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT - Failed
>
> -- Performing Test HAVE_SOLARIS_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT
>
> -- Performing Test HAVE_SOLARIS_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT - Failed

Afterwards, I found that I made mistakes in choosing CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and libzip's CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. Just remind that zlib and libzip should be installed in the same path. And libpng should be installed in an identical path to the previous one.