# Unresolved External symbol __imp__zip_open with libzip (LNK2001)

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, zlib, libzip

I recently compiled libzip (and zlib) statically on windows 10 and i'm playing with it on visual Studio 2017.I followed instructions on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507893/libzip-with-visual-studio-2010),adapted it a bit to build with VS2017,and modified CMakelists.txt to build the library statically:

I added this to the end of the file :

```
ADD_LIBRARY(zipstatic STATIC ${LIBZIP_SOURCES} ${LIBZIP_EXTRA_FILES} ${LIBZIP_OPSYS_FILES})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(zipstatic PROPERTIES VERSION 3.0 SOVERSION 3 )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(zipstatic ${ZLIB_LIBRARY} ${OPTIONAL_LIBRARY})
INSTALL(TARGETS zipstatic
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

I also used patch from [here](https://github.com/ctabin/libzippp/tree/master/lib) to get rid of `STDIN_FILENO` error when compiling libzip.

Build processes went fine,i added `zlibstatic.lib` and `libzipstatic.lib` to my linker options,and set up Runtime Library to `/MT`

I wrote this tiny code to see if everything's working:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <zip.h>
#include <zlib.h>




int main()
{
    zip *archive = zip_open("C:\\test.zip", ZIP_CREATE, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

This kind of error often appears when linking against static lib instead of DLL's,but i compiled libzip statically (and i need to use static linking),so what do I have to do ?

EDIT : zipstatic.lib summary:

```
      C8 .data
      60 .debug$F
    45C4 .debug$S
    21BD .drectve
    2690 .rdata
   113C1 .text$mn
```

and zlibstatic.lib's summary :

```
    50 .debug$F
    860 .debug$S
    2C1 .drectve
    4317 .rdata
    ADB6 .text$mn
```

Comment: Did you add path where linker need to look for `zlibstatic.lib` and `libzipstatic.lib`?

Comment: @VTT Missing the path doesn't result in a _undefined reference_ error.

Comment: @user0042 It may actually if incorrect library version is found.

Comment: @VTT Good point, yes.

Comment: @VTT yes : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/44/6/1509791422-capture-d-ecran-58.png

Comment: You should check what actually is contained in those static libraries using dumpbin tool. Maybe it wasn't built correctly.

Comment: You should make sure your project does not define `ZLIB_DLL`.

Comment: @Michaël Roy : The only place I see `ZLIB_DLL` is in `zipconf.h`,with a `ifdef ZLIB_DLL.....`,but I didn't see any `define ZLIB_DLL` anywhere.

Comment: Maybe in the project configuration?  That macro is the only thing that could make your app expect the library coming from a dll.  The __imp_ prefix is a dead giveaway (that's linked to a __cdecl(dllimport) declaration).  Look in both your VS project and in the cmake project for the library.  You can also try adding `#undef ZLIB_DLL` in your stdafx.h

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Thanks for the hint with the dllimport. It pointed me to the solution on my side: As I want to use static libs of libzip I need to define `ZIP_STATIC` in my project preprocessor settings. The header expects this define when using static libs, otherwise it adds the dllimport via the ZIP_EXTERN define.

Comment: Glad to hear you could move forward on your project.