# getopt() in ANSI C

Tags: c, parameter-passing, getopt, ansi-c

I am working on `OPNET` and for that, I need the windows equivalent `getopt()` function in ANSI C language.

I need to call `getopt()` similar like :

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hadp:s")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
        case 'a':
            break;
        case 'd':
            dummy = 1;
            break;
        case 'p':
            res = atoi(optarg);
            if (1 <= res )
                break;
            else
                usage(argv[0]);
                break;
        case 's':
            use_decimal = 0;
            break;
        case 'h':
        default:
            usage(argv[0]);
    }
}
```

Now, when I compile, I am getting error that `getopt()` is undefined. I defined its header file but it can not be included in OPNET. So, I wanted to ask that how should I overcome this problem.

Comment: can you post the exact error message

Comment: Have you included this file #include <unistd.h>

Comment: I am getting this error : getopt is undefined; Assuming extern returning int

Comment: Please note that getopt isn't windows command. This works fine also in Linux for example. Have you included getopt.h header file?

Comment: Yes, I tried to include unistd.h but it is not supported on OPNET. So, thats why , getopt() is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getopt()` is not available in Windows. You can compile it though. Download the files from http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/svn/acct/trunk/lib and compile.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404690/376535) someone has compiled it in *VS2010*, So I think you wont face any problem.