# strcmp failing to compare strings properly

Tags: c, libc, strcmp

I'm having trouble using `strcmp` in C.

I'm trying to compare a program's arguments using `strcmp` but even though the strings are the same it doesn't work. Here is the portion of code.

```
while(strcmp(argv[i], "-e") != 0)
```

So for i = 11 if I print the value of `argv[i]` I get

```
printf("String %s i %d", argv[i],i);

>> String -e i 11
```

But the while keeps on going. Any ideas why this is happening?

Code:

```
while(strcmp(argv[i], "-e") != 0 || i != argc)
{
    printf("String %s i %d", argv[i],i);
    if(!isdigit((unsigned char)*argv[i]) && strcmp(argv[i], "-t") != 0)
    {
        archivo = fopen(argv[i] , "r");
        TOT_IMG = TOT_IMG + 1;
        for(t=0;t<NUM_FUNC_TRAZO;t++)
        {
            for(d=0;d<NUM_FUNC_DIAMETRICA;d++)
            {
                for(c=0;c<NUM_FUNC_CIRCO;c++)
                {
                    if (fscanf(archivo, "%s",el) != EOF)
                    {
                        par->vector_circo[t][d][c] = strtod(el,NULL);
                        par->clase = clase;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        par_temp = par;
        par->siguiente = (parametros_lista) malloc(sizeof(parametros_elem));
        par = par->siguiente;
        par->anterior = par_temp;
    }
    else
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "-t") != 0)
        {
            clase = atoi(argv[i]);
            CLASES = CLASES + 1;
        }
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Sure you didn't forget to `i++;`?

Comment: Paste the full code rather than two excerpts with no explanation of how they're connected.

Comment: Nope I'm following the value of i with the debugger and it's fine. I'll post the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this:

```
while(strcmp(argv[i], "-e") != 0 || i != argc)
```

OK, so let's assume `strcmp` correctly returns `0` when `argv[i]` is "e". We'll assume this because it's *exceedingly* unlikely that there's a bug in your library implementation of `strcmp`.

What happens if `strcmp` returns 0? Well, things don't just stop, your code checks whether `i != argc` is true. Is it? My psychic debugging skills tell me that you should look into that second part of the `while`.

You may also want to note that it's possible that your code could, potentially, access `argv[argc]`, which is `NULL`. You may get lucky if `strcmp` is lenient when the input is `NULL`, but it's a bug that you should fix.

Comment: I would add that `while(i < argc && strcmp(argv[i], "-e") != 0)` is probably a better choice here.

Comment: hmmm ok, but I'm using "||" on the while statement so the first part of the while should act independently from the second part shouldn't it? I'm going to delete the second part to check it

Comment: @Omri: Cool, you learn something new every day. Thanks, I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: @Atirag think of how `||` operates - if the left hand side is false, it checks the right, if the left hand side is true, it doesn't check the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather recommend you to use [getopt (3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt). This is widely used approach to parameters parsing conforming with POSIX.

Also there was another question related to achieving `getopt.h` interface on windows: [getopt.h: Compiling UNIX C-Code in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404448/getopt-h-compiling-unix-c-code-in-windows). What's important it is answered (Xgetopt) so portability should be not a case.

Comment: getopt is NOT a part of the C standard. Its POSIX.

Comment: @cli_hlt POSIX defines the "POSIX C standard library".

Comment: IEEE POSIX has nothing to do with the ANSI C standard. Google will explain it to you. @Roman you should clarify your answer there.

Comment: @cli_hit where did you found word 'ANSI' even in original post (OK, now I at all deleted word 'standard' to not feed trolls)? Yes, it's POSIX, isn't it standard? Especially for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library

Comment: @RomanNikitchenko POSIX is a standard, it defines POSIX compliant operating systems. POSIX compliant operating systems(!) require a POSIX C library. *nix is such an OS, for example. OTOH, Windows is not. ANSI C is the standard of the C programming language. ANSI C conformant programs run on whatever system that has an ANSI C conformant compiler. ANSI C has also a standard library, which together with the language description defines the programming language C. It is very important not to mix these things up.