# compiling GCC project with visual studio

Tags: c, gcc

I have a project that compiling with GCC, and now I want open and run it with visual studio.what should I do?

I created new C project in visual studio and then add .c files to Source Files and add .h files to Header Files,too. But what should I do for makefile?

I see these error:

```
Error   9   error LNK2005: _main already defined in basic00.obj fp.obj

Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _optind   fp.obj

Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _optopt   fp.obj

Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _optarg   fp.obj

Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _getopt referenced in function _main  fp.obj

Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _opterr   fp.obj

Error   15  fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\project.c\Debug\project.c.exe
```

Comment: possibly correlated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404448/getopt-h-compiling-linux-c-code-in-windows In short getopt is from POSIX, but VS 2008 does not support it. Either rewrite your code or supply some drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to remove the second `main()` function.
2. You're using `optind`, `optopt` etc. These functions are defined in **POSIX** library, VS compiler doesn't have these ones. You need to remove these calls.