# How to pass file path to program as argument if it runs from environment variable? C++

Tags: c++, environment-variables, environment

Im making college project to code and decode files. I want it to run from command line something like this:

> myapp file_name -code

> myapp file_name -decode

How do I get path to file in directory where I opened CMD and how do I save file to same directory?
My code if its needed:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
if (argv[2] == "code" || argv[2] == "c") {
    try {
        WriteAllBytes("coded.gau", StringToCharVector(Code(CharVectorToString(ReadAllBytes(argv[1])))));
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Exception!" << std::endl;
    }
} else if (argv[2] == "decode" || argv[2] == "d") {
    try {
        WriteAllBytes("coded.gau", StringToCharVector(Decode(CharVectorToString(ReadAllBytes(argv[1])))));
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Exception!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Don't forget about things like [`getopt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) to make argument parsing easier and more reliable. This code will crash, hard, if `argc` isn't at least 3.

Comment: The argv[2] checking is wrong, it is not obvious why you can't debug this.  In VS use Project > Properties > Debugging > "Command Arguments".

Answer (score -1):

You can use

- [Boost.Program_Options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/program_options.html):

```cpp
// Declare the supported options.
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("compression", po::value<int>(), "set compression level")
;

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);
```

- Glibc [getopt()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html):

```cpp
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1)
    switch (c)
      {
      case 'a':
        aflag = 1;
        break;
      case 'b':
        bflag = 1;
        break;
...
```

See rest of the example: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html

- [QCommandLineParser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html):

```cpp
QCommandLineParser parser;
parser.setApplicationDescription("Test helper");
parser.addHelpOption();
parser.addVersionOption();
parser.addPositionalArgument("source", QCoreApplication::translate("main", "Source file to copy."));
parser.addPositionalArgument("destination", QCoreApplication::translate("main", "Destination directory."));
```

Rest of the example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html#details

Comment: Is there no way to do this without libraries?

Comment: You can parse it your self, What is your mean by _without libraries_ ? your program already linked to libc which you could use `getopt()`.

Comment: I thought getopt() is only for Linux

Comment: If you follow the rule of asking a good question we guide you better than you ask your question chunk by chunk, See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404524/9248466